# Comment traduire « (the) vulnerable world hypothesis » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs, déterminants, philosophie

> Let us introduce the hypothesis that the urn of creativity contains at
>   least one black ball. We can refer to this as the *​vulnerable world
>   hypothesis*​. Intuitively, the hypothesis is that there is some level
>   of technology at which civilization almost certainly gets destroyed
>   unless quite extraordinary and historically unprecedented degrees of
>   preventive policing and/or global governance are implemented. More
>   precisely:
>
> VWH: If technological development continues then a set of capabilities
>   will at some point be attained that make the devastation of
>   civilization extremely likely, unless civilization sufficiently exits
>   the semi-anarchic default condition.
>
> [ [Nick Bostrom](https://nickbostrom.com/), [*The Vulnerable World Hypothesis*](https://nickbostrom.com/papers/vulnerable.pdf) (2018),
>   University of Oxford (Future of Humanity Institute) ]

Peut-on expliquer comment traduire « (the) [vulnerable](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/vulnerable/623017) [world](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/world/624905) [hypothesis](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/hypothesis/587627) » en fonction de ce contexte et en portant une attention particulière à la séquence des mots, au déterminant, à la relation entre l'adjectif et le nom *world*, tout en évitant l'« interférence » pouvant provenir de cooccurrences similaires de ces mots usuels si c'est le cas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut faire une construction parallèle à des expressions similaires, comme *(the) just-world hypothesis*, expression qui a le même ordre de mots, et les mêmes relations entre les mots qui la composent. Cette expression se traduit par "hypothèse du monde juste" selon wikipédia. On obtiendrait alors **hypothèse du monde vulnérable**.

Je ne note pas d'interférence particulière qui pourrait être due à une autre co-occurrence entre ces termes; quant au risque que l'on ne sache pas si on parle du monde au sens de *world* ou du monde au sens de *people*, je ne considérerais pas qu'il y a de gros risque car cette deuxième acception n'est pas d'un registre aussi soutenu que "hypothèse". Si on voulait absolument éviter ce risque, on pourrait dire "hypothèse de la vulnérabilité du monde" ou "hypothèse d'un monde vulnérable", mais je pense que c'est superflu et rend l'expression moins "claquante" (ce qui est encore plus important si l'expression de trouve ensuite en titre d'un livre).

Cela dit, à lire seulement la définition qui en est donnée, les mots qui me viendraient à l'esprit seraient plutôt quelque chose comme "hypothèse de la vulnérabilité inéluctable" ou "hypothèse du cataclysme par défaut". Mais à ce stade c'est plus de l'édition que de la traduction...

Comment: Sans doute l'idée que pour moi « du monde vulnérable » c'est une manière familière de parler de personnes vulnérables et sans le contexte ça me donne l'impression que c'est une hypothèse originant de ces personnes-là. J'ai remarqué que le moteur DeepL substantive aussi _vulnérable_, je ne trouve pas que c'est de l'édition, dans le sens que _world_ ne veut jamais dire _people_ à ma connaissance en anglais etc. et le cœur de l'hypothèse ce n'est pas l'idée du monde, c'est une propriété de ce monde ou l'impact que ce monde pourrait subir, donc j'apprécie qu'on évoque le substantif...

Comment: Peut-être que c'est _vulnérabilité_ qui devrait recevoir un complément du nom, et peut-être pas _monde_, encore vu ce dont je parle dans le commentaire précédent. Je ne sais pas.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 si ce qui te gêne, c'est l'acception de "monde" ayant le sens d'une foule (*people*), je pense personnellement qu'il n'y a pas trop de risque mais il y a quelques variations possibles que j'ajoute à la réponse